# Kubectl is working but I can't access any of the components

Tags: kubernetes, weave

We have a small private k8s cluster and until this morning everything was working but as of this morning just kubectl is working and no traffic is going through.

I mean I can launch new deployments, kill them, etc and I can see that they are up and running

But when I want to access them via http, amqp, etc I can't.
I was looking at our nginx logs and tried to go to the homepage but there was no log in nginx and nothing loaded in browser which means that no traffic received by nginx.
We are using Weave net as our CNI.

I checked the dns logs and also tested it and dns is working. I don't know where to start looking for solving this problem, any suggestion?

## Update

After some hours the problem almost solved and now I can access my applications but I want to ask another question which is very related to this:

Is there a way that we can detect that the problem is because of networking or it is from the cluster networking (the internal k8s network)? I am asking this because in the past I had a problem with k8s dns and this time I thought something is wrong with the k8s CNI.

## Update 2

Now I see this error in weave:

```
ERRO: 2019/09/27 11:10:03.358321 Captured frame from MAC (d2:14:2a:47:62:d9) to (02:01:5b:b9:8e:fd) associated with another peer 4a:8d:75:d7:59:ff(serflex-argus-2)
```

And my environment:

- Kubernetes version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.1", GitCommit:"b7394102d6ef778017f2ca4046abbaa23b88c290", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-04-08T17:11:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.3", GitCommit:"2d3c76f9091b6bec110a5e63777c332469e0cba2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-19T11:05:50Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

- Cloud provider or hardware configuration:
  In house private cluster contains of 5 nodes and set up with kubeadm.
- OS (e.g: cat /etc/os-release):
  All machines are running Ubuntu 18.04.3
- Kernel (e.g. uname -a):
  Linux k8s-master 4.15.0-62-generic #69-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 4 20:55:53 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Install tools:
  kubeadm
- Network plugin and version (`weave status`):

```
/home/weave # ./weave --local status
        Version: 2.5.2 (up to date; next check at 2019/09/27 15:12:49)
        Service: router
       Protocol: weave 1..2
           Name: 02:01:5b:b9:8e:fd(k8s-master)
     Encryption: disabled
  PeerDiscovery: enabled
        Targets: 1
    Connections: 5 (4 established, 1 failed)
          Peers: 5 (with 20 established connections)
 TrustedSubnets: none
        Service: ipam
         Status: ready
```

- Docker version:
  `Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfc`

Comment: Can you access your apps using curl from kubernetes machine?
It's sound like network issue.

Comment: I thought about it but I am not sure if this is a networking problem of our private datacenter or it is related to Weavenet. Randomly I can access the components either via curl or browser, it is like 60% failure.

Comment: kubectl get pods  should be able to tell as what service type it is. According you can access services

Comment: I think you didn't get the problem. The problem is not service type, I know what service type we have with full details because I wrote them and setup the cluster. The problem is from this morning the cluster network started to face problems without any error in any of the pods neither my platform nor k8s pods.

Comment: Hi @AVarf,
Can you share us some dns and weave net services logs from your cluster? You can do that by getting pods from kube-system namespace.

`kubectl get pods -n kube-system`

And then print logs with following command:

`kubectl logs <pod-name> -n kube-system`

Comment: Hi @jt97 , checking the logs was the first thing I did and as I wrote in my question there was nothing there. Dns doesn't generate any log either the traffic goes through or not but very strangely now I see an error  (I removed some extra characters in MAC) in weave net: `ERRO: 2019/09/27 11:25:03.361871 Captured frame from MAC (d9) to (fd) associated with another peer ff(serflex-argus-2)`. This is the first time that I see any error and I am happy :)

Comment: @AVarf, What versions of kubernetes, docker and weave net do You have installed?

Comment: I updated my question and added all the information.

Comment: @AVarf, The weave net error could have been because of reused addresses in pods that were deployed and killed while you had network issues. So in many cases it doesn't mean anything. There is too little information to be sure that it was cluster network issue. Do you have any monitoring system running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution for this problem and I had to tear down the cluster and recreate it but this time I used Calico and after running for a week there was no problem.

The only thing I think could cause the problem was the 200Mb memory limit of the Weave and the fact that 4 out of 5 of my Weave pods were hitting that limit and also on their github I found that Weave has an issue with memleak and because of these I decided to change the CNI.